# extract xz file in python

Tags: python, lzma, xz

I have a file data.csv.xz. I want to extract the csv file but not manually. I find a way by using the package lzma. But when I pip install lama in python 3.8 in spyder, I got an error:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lzma (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for lzma

what's wrong with the version 3.8 ? And, is there any other way to accomplish this task?

Comment: `lzma` is part of the Python standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html#module-lzma So you should not need to install anything else and you can work with LZMA compressed (xz) files as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lzma` is part of the standard library of Python, so you won't find it in the PyPi indices.

To verify, simply fire up your python shell and just try :

```
>>> import lzma
>>>
```

It should work.

Answer (score 1):

lzma is a part of standard library of Python. You dont need to install it, instead you can directly import it.

You can refer this
https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html#module-lzma

Answer (score 1):

As said, you won't need to install `lzma`, as it is already in the pip standard library.

There's absolutely nothing wrong with your Python (hopefully).